ReactNative: Error "Could not find image file:///...."on iOS only after upgrade to 0.74
I have an app which is on the store and working fine.
I'm upgrading it from RN 0.71 to RN 0.74.5.
Everything work fine on Android, but on iOS I have one issue: All images received from the server, as base64 strings, are showing the warning message:

[javascript] Could not find image file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/87618C89-D581-492F-A083-3388DB17A364/Companion.app/data:image/png%3Bbase64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...5CYII=%0A.png

I tried to remove my Podfile.lock and Pods/ folder and re-install pods, but still no luck.
Here is my code of the <Image> component:
        <Image
          style={{
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            margin: 10
          }}
          source={
            item.photo ? { uri: `data:image/png;base64,${item.photo}` } : noLogo
          }
        />

Just to let you know, the noLogo is a required image:
const noLogo = require('../../img/no-logo.png')

When I remove my condition and only have noLogo, the image works.
